# check-in files in a branch in tfs through powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfvc

I have a tfs collection with a couple of branches and I want to do a check in through powershell. I usually first connect to the collection through: Get-tfsserver -Name "tfs:8080...". But I can't specify the branch name there. How can i do this?

Comment: Git or TFVC? In case of TFVC, you get the VersionControlServer from the your TfsTeamprojectCollection instance and when checking in, simply pass the path to the branch as ItemSpec. In case of Git, simply use a git client and forego the whole TFS client object model.

Comment: yes tfvc, would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: @EmmaJones, you should use the Windows PowerShell cmdlets which is installed with TFS Power Tool (adjudged from Get-tfsserver). Please check my reply below.

Answer (score 1):

To specify the branch name, you can define the branch use $ServerBranchLocation

A example of tfs checkin  PowerShell script

```
param (
    [string]$tfsServer = "TFSServerName",
    [string]$tfsLocation = "$/TFS/Project/serverbranch",
    [string]$localFolder ="c:\scripts",
    [string]$file,
    [string]$checkInComments = "Checked in from PowerShell"
    )
    $clientDll = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
    $versionControlClientDll = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"

    #Load the Assemblies
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($clientDll)
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($versionControlClientDll)
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($versionControlCommonDll)

    #Set up connection to TFS Server and get version control
    $tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($tfsServer)
    $versionControlType = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer]
    $versionControlServer = $tfs.GetService($versionControlType)

    #Create a "workspace" and map a local folder to a TFS location
    $workspace = $versionControlServer.CreateWorkspace("PowerShell Workspace",$versionControlServer.AuthenticatedUser)
    $workingfolder = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WorkingFolder($tfsLocation,$localFolder)
    $workspace.CreateMapping($workingFolder)
    $filePath = $localFolder + "\" + $file

    #Submit file as a Pending Change and submit the change
    $workspace.PendAdd($filePath)
    $pendingChanges = $workspace.GetPendingChanges()
    $workspace.CheckIn($pendingChanges,$checkInComments)

    #Delete the temp workspace
    $workspace.Delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell is:

```html
# Load TFS Client Assembly
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')

#Connect to TFS Server
[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer("https://name.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection")

#Add File
#Adds files and folders from a location in the local file system to a version control server for Team Foundation.

$WorkstationType = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workstation]
$WorkspaceInfo = $WorkstationType::Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo("localFolderForBranch")



# Get Collection
$Collection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($WorkspaceInfo.ServerUri)
$Collection.EnsureAuthenticated()

# Get Workspace.
$Global:Workspace = $WorkspaceInfo.GetWorkspace($Collection)

#Check in new file

$pendingChanges = $workspace.GetPendingChanges() 
$Comment = "checkin branch....."
$workspace.CheckIn($pendingChanges,$Comment)
```

Also have a check on the Version control steps in Windows PowerShell part in this blog for the details: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/28/protect-your-powershell-scripts-with-version-control.aspx